# Remove duplicate column values from a datatable without using LINQ

Tags: c#, ado.net, datatable, duplicates

Consider my datatable,

```
Id  Name  MobNo
1   ac    9566643707
2   bc    9944556612
3   cc    9566643707
```

How to remove the row `3` which contains duplicate `MobNo` column value in c# without using LINQ. I have seen similar questions on SO but all the answers uses LINQ.

Comment: When duplicates are found, how do you want to decide which one is to remain, and which one(s) are to be deleted?

Comment: @Tomas always the first one to remain...

Comment: Do you want to just get a set of records with unique mobile numbers or to remove the records with duplicates from the existing set?

Comment: @strelokstrelok ya i want the latter one...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following method did what i want....

```
public DataTable RemoveDuplicateRows(DataTable dTable, string colName)
    {
        Hashtable hTable = new Hashtable();
        ArrayList duplicateList = new ArrayList();

        //Add list of all the unique item value to hashtable, which stores combination of key, value pair.
        //And add duplicate item value in arraylist.
        foreach (DataRow drow in dTable.Rows)
        {
            if (hTable.Contains(drow[colName]))
                duplicateList.Add(drow);
            else
                hTable.Add(drow[colName], string.Empty);
        }

        //Removing a list of duplicate items from datatable.
        foreach (DataRow dRow in duplicateList)
            dTable.Rows.Remove(dRow);

        //Datatable which contains unique records will be return as output.
        return dTable;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are reading your CSV file ( a bit of pseudo code, but you get the picture ):

```
List<String> uniqueMobiles = new List<String>();

String[] fileLines = readYourFile();

for (String line in fileLines) {
   DataRow row = parseLine(line);
   if (uniqueMobiles.Contains(row["MobNum"])
   {
       continue;
   }
   uniqueMobiles.Add(row["MobNum"]);
   yourDataTable.Rows.Add(row);       
}
```

This will only load the records with unique mobiles into your data table.

Answer (score 1):

This is the simplest way  .

**

```
var uniqueContacts = dt.AsEnumerable()
                       .GroupBy(x=>x.Field<string>("Email"))
                       .Select(g=>g.First());
```

**
I found it in this thread 
 [LINQ to remove duplicate rows from a datatable based on the value of a specific row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27599261/linq-to-remove-duplicate-rows-from-a-datatable-based-on-the-value-of-a-specific)

what actually was for me that I return it as datatable

```
DataTable uniqueContacts = dt.AsEnumerable()
                           .GroupBy(x=>x.Field<string>("Email"))
                           .Select(g=>g.First()).CopyToDataTable();
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look up the inner workings on DISTINCT before running this on your sharp DB (be sure to back up!), but if it works as I think it does (grabbing the first value) you should be able to use (something very similar to) the following SQL:

```
DELETE FROM YourTable WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT Id, MobNo FROM YourTable);
```

Comment: @Pandiya, well, why didn't you say so? =)

Answer (score 0):

You can use "IEqualityComparer" in C#