# Which way is the best for removing duplicates from a dataTable with multiple columns

Tags: c#

Which way is the best for removing duplicates from a dataTable for multiple columns?I mean below code is only for a single column.

```
public DataTable RemoveDuplicateRows(DataTable dTable, string colName)
{
   Hashtable hTable = new Hashtable();
   ArrayList duplicateList = new ArrayList();

   //Add list of all the unique item value to hashtable, which stores combination of key, value pair.
   //And add duplicate item value in arraylist.
   foreach (DataRow drow in dTable.Rows)
   {
      if (hTable.Contains(drow[colName]))
         duplicateList.Add(drow);
      else
         hTable.Add(drow[colName], string.Empty); 
   }

   //Removing a list of duplicate items from datatable.
   foreach (DataRow dRow in duplicateList)
      dTable.Rows.Remove(dRow);

   //Datatable which contains unique records will be return as output.
      return dTable;
}
```

I tried using string[] colName. It throws error at `dTable.Rows.Remove(dRow);`

Please suggest.

Comment: Hate to repost my own answer. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/24387929/815600

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest and most readable is using `Linq-to-DataTable`:

```
var groups = from r in dTable.AsEnumerable()
             group r by new
             {
                 Col1 = r.Field<String>("Column1"),
                 Col2 = r.Field<String>("Column2"),
             };

// if you only want the first row of each group:
DataTable distinctTable = groups.Select(g => g.First()).CopyToDataTable();
```

Notes: [`Enumerable.GroupBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501.aspx) groups the `DataRows` by an anonymous type with two properties(`Col1` and `Col2`) which are initialized from a `DataRow` fields `Column1` and `Column2`.

So you get   groups of `IEnumerable<DataRow>`. `Enumerable.First()` returns the first `DataRow` of each group (you could also use different methods to select the row you want to keep, for example by ordering by a date field).

Then `CopyToDataTable` creates a new DataTable from the (now) distinct DataRows.

---

Here's a possible implementation if you're using .NET 2:

implementation of a custom `IEqualityComparer<Object[]>` for the dictionary:

```
class ObjectArrayComparer : IEqualityComparer<Object[]>
{
    public bool Equals(Object[] x, Object[] y)
    {
        if (x == null && y == null) return true;
        if (x == null || y == null) return false;
        if (x.Length  !=  y.Length) return false;       

        for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
        {
            if (x[i] == null && y[i] == null) continue;
            if (x[i] == null || y[i] == null) return false;
            if (!x[i].Equals(y[i])) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Object[] obj)
    {
        int hash = 0;
        if (obj != null)
        {
            hash = (hash * 17) + obj.Length;
            foreach (Object o in obj)
            {
                hash *= 17;
                if (o != null) hash = hash + o.GetHashCode();
            }
        }
        return hash;
    }
}
```

your `RemoveDuplicateRows` method:

```
public DataTable RemoveDuplicateRows(DataTable dTable, String[] colNames)
{
    var hTable = new Dictionary<object[], DataRow>(new ObjectArrayComparer());

    foreach (DataRow drow in dTable.Rows)
    {
        Object[] objects = new Object[colNames.Length];
        for (int c = 0; c < colNames.Length; c++)
            objects[c] = drow[colNames[c]];
        if (!hTable.ContainsKey(objects))
            hTable.Add(objects, drow);
    }

    // create a clone with the same columns and import all distinct rows
    DataTable clone = dTable.Clone();
    foreach (var kv in hTable)
        clone.ImportRow(kv.Value);

    return clone;
}
```

testing:

```
var table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("Colum1", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("Colum2", typeof(int));
table.Columns.Add("Colum3", typeof(string));

Random r = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    table.Rows.Add("Colum1_" + r.Next(1, 10), r.Next(1, 10), "Colum3_" + r.Next(1, 10));
}
int rowCount = table.Rows.Count; // 100
var unique = RemoveDuplicateRows(table, new[] { "Colum1", "Colum2" });
int uniqueRowCount = unique.Rows.Count; // around 55-65
```

Comment: :Thanks for the answer.I really didn`t get the concept here.Where are we removing duplicates here????

Comment: @user1495475: Added some comments which are hopefully helpful.

Comment: Tim:Assembly is missing for "AsEnumerable".I tried including system.data.datatable still same error.What`s wrong?

Comment: @user1495475: Are you using at least .NET 35 and have you added a reference to `System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll`?

Comment: Tim:I`m using target framework as version 2.0.And I haven`t used ur reference System.Data.DataSetExtensions,even this is also throwing error.Please suggest.

Comment: @user1495475: As i've mentioned in my last comment. You need at least .NET 3.5 for LINQ and i would suggest to mention this restriction next time (tag it accordingly).

Comment: Tim:Sorry for that.Please suggest me an answer for my version.

Comment: @user1495475: I've edited my answer to provide a possible implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Distinct on Datatable.Select ... [Link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetdataset/thread/ed9c6a6a-a93e-4bf5-a892-d8471b84aa3b/)

Refer this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200751/how-do-i-remove-duplicates-from-a-datatable-altogether-based-on-a-columns-value)

Answer (score 0):

Below is your code with several amends of mine.
The main idea is to add to `HashTable`(Dictionary<> in my code) not value of only one column but values of specified columns and threat them these several values in atomic way(like single one).

```
            // your code with minor amends
    public DataTable RemoveDuplicateRows(DataTable dTable, string[] colNames)
    {
        // note that strongly typed dictionary has replaced the hash table + it uses custom comparer 
        var hTable = new Dictionary<DataRowInfo, string>();
        var duplicateList = new ArrayList();

        //Add list of all the unique item value to hashtable, which stores combination of key, value pair.
        //And add duplicate item value in arraylist.
        foreach (DataRow drow in dTable.Rows)
        {
            var dataRowInfo = new DataRowInfo(drow, colNames);

            if (hTable.ContainsKey(dataRowInfo))
                duplicateList.Add(drow);
            else
                hTable.Add(dataRowInfo, string.Empty);
        }

        //Removing a list of duplicate items from datatable.
        foreach (DataRow dRow in duplicateList)
            dTable.Rows.Remove(dRow);

        //Datatable which contains unique records will be return as output.
        return dTable;
    }

    // Helper classes

    // contains values of specified columns
    internal sealed class DataRowInfo
    {
        public object[] Values { get; private set; }

        public DataRowInfo(DataRow dataRow, string[] columns)
        {
            Values = columns.Select(c => dataRow[c]).ToArray();
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj))
                return true;

            var other = obj as DataRowInfo;
            if (other == null)
                return false;

            return Equals(other);
        }

        private bool Equals(DataRowInfo other)
        {
            if (this.Values.Length != other.Values.Length)
                return false;
            for (int i = 0; i < this.Values.Length; i++)
            {
                if (AreObjectsEqual(this.Values[i], other.Values[i]))
                    return false;
            }

            return true;
        }

        private static bool AreObjectsEqual(object left, object right)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(left, right))
                return true;

            if (ReferenceEquals(left, null))
                return false;

            if (ReferenceEquals(right, null))
                return false;

            if (left.GetType() != right.GetType())
                return false;

            return left.Equals(right);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            unchecked
            {
                int hashCode = 0;
                foreach (var value in this.Values)
                {
                    hashCode = hashCode ^ ((value != null ? value.GetHashCode() : 0) * 397);
                }
                return hashCode;
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope this will help.

**UPDATE**
Simplified code a bit.

Comment: aleksey:Thanks for the answer.I don`t think so this one is a better way for that.Don`t we have a simple one for this??

Comment: @user1495475: I've simplified code a bit and I'm afraid I can't something simpler. BTW, despite solution has much more code then that one that you've posted, it's not that complex: it just adds to hashtable array of values(wrapped into helper data structure) instead of single primitive value.