# C# - Remove rows with the same column value from a DataTable

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, filtering

I have a `DataTable` which looks like this:

```
 ID   Name    DateBirth
.......................
 1     aa      1.1.11
 2     bb      2.3.11
 2     cc      1.2.12
 3     cd      2.3.12
```

Which is the fastest way to remove the rows with the same ID, to get something like this (keep the first occurrence, delete the next ones):

```
 ID   Name    DateBirth
.......................
 1     aa      1.1.11
 2     bb      2.3.11
 3     cd      2.3.12
```

I don't want to double pass the table rows, because the row number is big.
I want to use some LinQ if possible, but I guess it will be a big query and I have to use a comparer.

Comment: What have you tried? Is it just about the ID? The other fields are irrelevant?

Comment: The common way. 2 for's and verify every row's ID field. If it is duplicate , delete it. But this is basic and low performance. And yes, the other fields are irrelevant. Just ID is important.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use LINQ to DataTable, to distinct based on column `ID`, you can *group by* on this column, then do *select* first:

```
  var result = dt.AsEnumerable()
                 .GroupBy(r => r.Field<int>("ID"))
                 .Select(g => g.First())
                 .CopyToDataTable();
```

Answer (score 3):

I was solving the same situation and found it quite interesting and would like to share my finding.

1. If rows are to be distinct based on **ALL COLUMNS**.

```
DataTable newDatatable = dt.DefaultView.ToTable(true, "ID", "Name", "DateBirth");
```

The columns you mention here, only those will be returned back in `newDatatable`.

2. If distinct based on one column and column type is **int** then I would prefer `LINQ` query.

```
  DataTable newDatatable = dt.AsEnumerable()
                           .GroupBy(dr => dr.Field<int>("ID"))
                           .Select(dg => dg).Take(1)
                           .CopyToDataTable();
```

3. If distinct based on one column and column type is **string** then I would prefer loop.

```
List<string> toExclude = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    var idValue = (string)dt.Rows[i]["ID"];
    if (toExclude.Contains(idValue))
    {
        dt.Rows.Remove(dt.Rows[i]);
        i--;
    }
    toExclude.Add(glAccount);
}
```

Third being my favorite.

I may have answered few things which are not asked in the question. It was done in good intent and with little excitement as well.

Hope it helps.

Comment: What if `distinct` is based on two columns? Not one (i.e., `id` in above case).

Answer (score 2):

you can try this

```
DataTable uniqueCols = dt.DefaultView.ToTable(true, "ID");
```

Answer (score 2):

Not necessarily the most efficient approach, but maybe the most readable:

```
table = table.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(row => row.Field<int>("ID"))
    .Select(rowGroup => rowGroup.First())
    .CopyToDataTable();
```

Linq is also more powerful. For example, if you want to change the logic and not select the first (arbitrary) row of each id-group but the last according to `DateBirth`:

```
table = table.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(row => row.Field<int>("ID"))
    .Select(rowGroup => rowGroup
                          .OrderByDescending(r => r.Field<DateTime>("DateBirth"))
                          .First())
    .CopyToDataTable();
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Get a record count for each `ID`

```
var rowsToDelete = 
    (from row in dataTable.AsEnumerable()
    group row by row.ID into g
    where g.Count() > 1
```

2. Determine which record to keep (don't know your criteria; I will just sort by DoB then `Name` and keep first record) and select the rest

```
select g.OrderBy( dr => dr.Field<DateTime>( "DateBirth" ) ).ThenBy( dr => dr.Field<string>( "Name" ) ).Skip(1))
```

3. Flatten

```
.SelectMany( g => g );
```

4. Delete rows

```
rowsToDelete.ForEach( dr => dr.Delete() );
```

5. Accept changes

```
dataTable.AcceptChanges();
```

Answer (score 1):

Heres a way to achive this,
All you need to use [moreLinq](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) library use its function `DistinctBy`

**Code:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var DistinctByIdColumn = getDT2().AsEnumerable()
                                   .DistinctBy(
                                   row => new { Id = row["Id"] });
  DataTable dtDistinctByIdColumn = DistinctByIdColumn.CopyToDataTable();
}


public DataTable getDT2()
{
   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
   dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(string));
   dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
   dt.Columns.Add("Dob", typeof(string));
   dt.Rows.Add("1", "aa","1.1.11");
   dt.Rows.Add("2", "bb","2.3.11");
   dt.Rows.Add("2", "cc","1.2.12");
   dt.Rows.Add("3", "cd","2.3.12");
   return dt;
}
```

**OutPut:** As what you expected

[image]

[**For moreLinq sample code view my blog**](http://satindersinght.blogspot.in/2013/04/morelinq-distinctby-how-to-remove.html)