# LINQ to remove duplicate rows from a datatable based on the value of a specific row

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, duplicates

I have seen the following solution used for removing duplicate rows in a `DataTable` using `LINQ`:

Say if we have a `DataTable` with duplicate rows called `dt`, then the following statemend apparently does the job:

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> uniqueContacts = dt.AsEnumerable().Distinct(DataRowComparer.Default);
```

But this is only removing duplicate rows that are identical. What I want to do is to remove all the rows that have duplicate values of a specific row.

E.g. If we have a datatable with a row called "Email", how can we remove all the rows that have the same email value?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

simple way: use `GroupBy`:

```
var uniqueContacts = dt.AsEnumerable()
                       .GroupBy(x=>x.Field<string>("Email"))
                       .Select(g=>g.First());
```

you can also try use `Distinct`:

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();  
    dt.Columns.Add("ID");  
    dt.Columns.Add("FirstName");  
    dt.Columns.Add("Email");  
    dt.Rows.Add(1,"Tim","tim@mail.com");
    dt.Rows.Add(2,"Tim1","tim@mail.com");
    dt.Rows.Add(3,"Tim2","tim2@mail.com");
    dt.Rows.Add(4,"Tim3","tim3@mail.com");

    dt.AsEnumerable().Distinct(new DataRowComparer()).Dump();
```

Custom row comparer:

```
 public class DataRowComparer : IEqualityComparer<DataRow>  
    {  
        public bool Equals(DataRow t1, DataRow t2)  
        {  
            return (t1.Field<string>("Email")==t2.Field<string>("Email"));  
        }  
        public int GetHashCode(DataRow t)  
        {  
            return t.ToString().GetHashCode();  
        }  
    }
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049.aspx

Comment: Looks promising. Gonna test it right now, but in your `GroupBy` answer, how do I remove the rows? Isn't it only selecting the duplicates now? Sorry I am not very good with `LINQ`?

Comment: @Pedram  `Select(g=>g.First())` means: select first item in group

Comment: Simple way is good, though I believe you should use Email field hashcode in comparer approach.

Comment: The conversion a VB.NET is the following Dim uniqueContacts = dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(Function(x) x.Field(Of String)("Email")).[Select](Function(g) g.First())